# Google Analytics Events - when are they send?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

My "application" is a single web page (myPage.html) displaying items on a Google Map. So it is not a scenario where the user navigates among several pages.

Therefor I am using events to track the interactions. However, I find it strange to believe what I see in the statistics.

I have checked the events for syntax and it seems to be OK.

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyApp', 'ChangeTav', newTab]);
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyApp', 'Load', 'itemType', loadTime]);
 ....
```

What I wonder about, I do add Arrays to to `_gaq` object, but when are these actually send? What happens if the user closes the browser? And is there a way for me to "force" sending these values?

The other way around, user stays on the page for some time, values get added to `_gaq`, but how I do make sure they not getting lost?

-- Update --

With the push I simply add an Array to an Array, or is this wrong? So in this particular moment nothing happens, I did not see any callbacks or overridden methods. Please correct if I am missing something.

-- Update 2 --

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html

It seems to be different whether I use sync or async. For async (I am using) ...

*To push an API call onto the queue, you must convert it from the traditional JavaScript syntax into a command array. **Command arrays are simply JavaScript arrays** that conform to a certain format. The first element in a command array is the name of the tracker object method you want to call. It must be a string. The rest of the elements are the arguments you want to pass to the tracker object method. These can be any JavaScript value.*

When I do init with `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` it becomes an array. However, I do never see values being removed from the queue (_gaq), so I'd assume they are never send.

--- OK, here we go ---

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi_gaq.html#_gaq.push

This function is named push so that an array can be used in the place of _gaq before Analytics has completely loaded. While Analytics is loading, commands will be pushed/queued onto the array. **When Analytics finishes loading, it replaces the array with the _gaq object** and executes all the queued commands. Subsequent calls to _gaq.push resolve to this function, which executes commands as they are pushed.

Comment: Your edits are the correct answer, not the answer you've accepted. You should post them as an answer and accept it.

Comment: My impression was that it is actually correct, they are sent when _gaq is initialized (became an object), which his depended from the init code location and time of debugging. Only I did not understand it from the beginning, since I was always seeing an array in my debugger. By your discussion I got more focused on that topic and did look deeper into it, I'd missed that without your answer! Thanks.

Comment: ysrb's answer isn't actively wrong; its just not as full as accurate as yours. (I didn't post an answer, but you should definitely post your edits as an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, it's send as soon as you call it. Provided that the _gaq has been initialized. Depends on where you put the GA init code.

Comment: How do they do it, I mean I do simply add an Array to an Array? Or is this wrong? I cannot see they have overridden the push method or something in the Debugger.

Comment: If you use firebug addon, there is a Net tab that will show you any data being posted on the background. So that _gaq.push function will trigger something on the Net tab. Give it a try.

Comment: Yes, right, my mistake, _gaq is an Array first and when GA is initialized it becomes an object with the push method. So it depends on time / situation when being debugged whether you see it as Array or Object with an "existing" push method....

Answer (score 0):

The `.push` method you are referring to is only for arrays. With Objects, you can define it yourself, you are not overriding anything.
Arrays in js can't have custom indexes / labels, if they do, they are objects.

If you run

```
var a= {"a":"b"};
var b  = ['a','b'];

b.push("c");
a.push("c","d");
```

You will get an error , function a.push is not defined.
a is an object, b is an array. The push function only exists in the prototype of Array.

To observe when exactly the stuff is tracked, you can use the Net panel in Firebug and check for a _utm.gif file being requested.

Comment: The idea with firebug is good. However, just for my understanding, maybe I am confused. _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MyApp', 'ChangeTav', newTab]); _gaq is an Array, and what I do push is an Array, correct? This means - as conclusion - there cannot be a "sending" within the push unless it is overridden.

Comment: no, _gaq is an Object (not an Array) with custom-defined function .push. I would have to check ga.js to tell you exactly what it does, but my best guess is it is obfuscated and minified, so...

Comment: Also, my best guess is that there truly is an Array as a propriety of _gaq where this really gets pushed, but the action itself is defined in the object _gaq.

Comment: It seems to be different (see my update above) whether you are using sync / async. In my debugger (VS2010) I do see it as array, while in FF I see it as an object. Very confusing ..... BTW, thanks for your effort.